# How to configure keyboard for hp 246 g6 notebook?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, hp

Since I did update from 18.04 to 20.04  my keyboard settings look like this.

[image]

and my keyboard layout is like this bellow

[image]

I tried this and it made it worse.

`setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br`

My issue is: my keymap configuration  is not the same of my keyboards, signals like pipe or slash disappear or setting in another place

Comment: What is the problem? Please edit your question to clarify.